# jquery mobile - html links to subdirectory break navigation

Tags: navigation, jquery-mobile

I want to link to page2.html which is in subdirectory /html

Page 2

When clicked I go from

```
http ://mysite.com/sub/sub/index.html
```

to

```
http ://mysite.com/sub/sub/html/page2.html
```

With Jquery Mobile enabled, I still get to the page, but the url look like this:

```
http ://mysite.com/sub/sub/index.html#/sub/sub/html/page2.html
```

This breaks any other navigation buttons when relative path is used.

[space in url is deliberate because site doesn't permit links]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like jQuery Mobile does not support relative paths unless you provide the URL.

See section head "resolving Relative Paths"

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/wiki/Refactor:-navigation-paths